# Set the number of keys/addresses in a wallet

Tags: bitcoin.conf

Is there a way to configure the number of keypairs (or addresses) created by `bitcoind` or `bitcoin-qt`?

I've looked at the [sample `bitcoin.conf` file](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File), but failed to find the relevant parameter.

Comment: You get a new keypair for each address. There is nothing to configure.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it:

```
# Pre-generate this many public/private key pairs, so wallet backups will be valid for
# both prior transactions and several dozen future transactions.
#keypool=100
```